# How do you use msgpack to replace copy.deepcopy in Python?

Tags: python

According to this post [What is a fast pythonic way to deepcopy just data from a python dict or list ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858084/what-is-a-fast-pythonic-way-to-deepcopy-just-data-from-a-python-dict-or-list) msgpack is 10 times faster than `copy.deepcopy` but I cannot figure out how to use it.

I tried

```
item2 = msgpack.unpack(msgpack.packb(item1))
```

In place of:

```
item2 = copy.deepcopy(item1)
```

But I get

```
File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 228, in msgpack._unpacker.unpack
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

The documentation located here http://msgpack-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html is incomprehensible but that's no surprise because just about all computer documentation is incomprehensible to me.

Comment: If you can't follow the documentation for msgpack, I am 100% certain that trying to use it to hack a marginally faster version of deepcopy is absolutely the wrong thing. Write the simplest most straightforward code you can, and worry about perfomance later.

Comment: No thank you.  My program just slowed down by a factor of 3 due to deepcopy.  If I can speed it up to the way it was before then I'm doing that.

Comment: Up to you :) There are implications to choosing serialization/deserialization over deepcopy, and its hard to say if your use case will be affected by those. THAT is why it is faster- it is not doing a lot of the stuff deepcopy is doing. Further, in the event that you really don't need the stuff deepcopy is doing, the most performant thing is almost certainly to write a simple method to copy exactly what you do need, since that will wind up doing less than msgpack or json.loads(json.dumps(x)) would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs, `msgpack.unpack` expects a stream, not a block of bytes:

```
>>> help(msgpack.unpack)
Help on built-in function unpack in module msgpack._unpacker:

    unpack(...)
        unpack(stream, object_hook=None, list_hook=None, bool use_list=1, encoding=None, unicode_errors='strict', object_pairs_hook=None, ext_hook=ExtType, Py_ssize_t max_str_len=2147483647, Py_ssize_t max_bin_len=2147483647, Py_ssize_t max_array_len=2147483647, Py_ssize_t max_map_len=2147483647, Py_ssize_t max_ext_len=2147483647)
```

Just as you used `packb` to pack the object, you should use `unpackb` to unpack it:

```
>>> item2 = msgpack.unpackb(msgpack.packb(item1))
```

Comment: Ok, I used `item2 = msgpack.unpackb(msgpack.packb(item1))` and no error was thrown but it seriously garbled my data and messed up my program.  So I think I'm probably going to give up on msgpack.

Comment: I tried using json `json.loads(json.dumps(object))` and although no error was thrown it broke my code.  Is it supposed to be the same as copy.deepcopy?

Comment: Actually, I've noticed that the problem stems from another list embedded within the list.  Maybe `json` does not deepcopy the embedded lists

Comment: Neither `msgpack` nor `json` should garble your data.  If you're getting odd results, it would help if you could post a new question that includes a complete reproducer. That will make it easier for us to help you out.

Comment: Sorry for using sloppy language.  What I meant was that msgpack turns unicode into raw strings which I cannot read.  And json and msgpack do not preserve the identity of references as seen in this example `list1 = [[[1,2]], [2,3]]
list2 = list1
list3 = [list1, list2]
list4 = copy.deepcopy(list3)
list4[0][0][0][0] = 4
list5 = json.loads(json.dumps(list3))
list5[0][0][0][0] = 4

>>> list5[0][1][0][0] = 1
>>> list4[0][1][0][0] = 4` sorry about the formatting but I do not know how to put code into comments.

Answer (score 0):

you are using packb() which returns packed bytes, so to unpack , should use unpackb()

```
unpacmsgpack.unpackb(msgpack.packb(item1))
```